# Proof of a subgroup question.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone help me with the following questions?

i) Prove that every proper subgroup $H$ (being a subset but not equal to) $S_n$ is cyclic, if $n = 3$.

ii) Prove that this is not true for $n \ge 4$.

iii) Do the cycles $σ = (1, 2, 3)$ and $τ = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$ generate $S_5$, 
i.e., $S_5 = \langle σ, τ\rangle$ ?
Explain without having to actually multiply these two cycles by each other.

Answer (score 0):

(i) $S_3$ has order $6$.

A proper subgroup has order $1$, $2$, or $3$.

Groups of that order are always cyclic because $2$ and $3$ are primes.

(ii) The subgroup $\{ (1), (12), (34), (12)(34) \}$ of $S_4$ is not cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

i) either look directly, or use Lagrange's result that $|H|$ must divide $|G|$;

ii) $S_3$ is not cyclic and is a proper subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\ge4$

iii) both these permutations are even, so the subgroup they generate cannot contain any of the transpositions.

Answer (score -1):

i) $|S_3|=6=2\cdot 3$, every proper subgroup of $S_3$ must have order dividing $6$ (and not equal to $6$), the only groups of orders $1,2,3$ are cyclic (up to isomorphism).

ii) Hint: $S_3$ is a subgroup of $S_4$ and $S_3$ is not cyclic (why?)

iii) Not sure atm